# Installing Connector C for Mariadb

Tags: mysql, c, centos, mariadb, connector

So, I want to use Mariadb. There is this Connector-C for it. 
https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-c/

How do I install it? Quiet frankly, the documentation for it is horrible. Even the src file for 3.0.5 is linked to 3.0.4 page.

I did not find a way to install the binary, and the documentation for building from src is quiet vague. I would prefer to know how to install both ways (binary and build from source)

I'm using CentOS7 64bit.

Comment: The documentation is in fact absolutely horrible. This is a good question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to install it would be to use the MariaDB package repository.

```
curl -sS https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup | sudo bash
sudo yum -y install MariaDB-devel
```

As for building from source, these steps should work on CentOS 7.

```
sudo yum -y install git gcc openssl-devel make cmake
git clone https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-c.git
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ../mariadb-connector-c/ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: The documentation also suggests to make a dir named build (the code for which you have provided as well), but where is the ideal location to make this dir?

Comment: when we do cmake, what is the default path where mariadb-connector-c is cloned on our local system?

Comment: By default CMake installs all programs to `/usr/local`. Most of the time you want to install it into `/usr` instead.

Comment: On the directory location, pretty much anywhere is fine. It won't be used after the installation is done so it can be removed.

Comment: if you want to specify another location, just use -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=your_location when running cmake.

Answer (score 7):

**Raspberry Pi OS**

cd to preferred build location. Then install (thanks to @markusjm!):

```
sudo apt install git gcc make cmake libssl-dev
git clone https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-c.git
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ../mariadb-connector-c/ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

Then add installation directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Note: my installation directory is `/usr/lib/mariadb`. If you cannot find this after your installation, search for e.g. `libmariadb.so`, a file that should reside in your installation folder.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/mariadb:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Afterwards you can finally `pip3 install mariadb`, if, like me, you tried to do that in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

And for Ubuntu 20.04...

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadb3 libmariadb-dev
```

Answer (score 6):

After you download [MariaDB Connector/C](https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/c/), un`tar` and `cd`. Then `mv` the executable first.

```
sudo mv -f bin/mariadb_config /usr/bin/
```

Now you can execute `mariadb_config` and will know where to put header and library files to build wheel for `mariadb`.

For example,

**Ubuntu 18.04**

```
sudo mv -f include/mariadb /usr/local/include/
sudo mv -f lib/mariadb     /usr/local/lib/
```

**CentOS 7 & Ubuntu 20.04**

```
sudo mv -f include/mariadb /usr/include/
sudo mv -f lib/mariadb     /usr/lib/
```

Finally, you could `pip install mariadb`. (Or, `export CFLAGS=-std=c99` may help.)

After, in the case you cannot `import mariadb`,

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/PATH/TO/where/you/mv/lib/mariadb
```